# Is there a generator/software that gives image dimensions - ideally to a spreadsheet?

Tags: image

Random question, sorry if not appropriate for stackoverflow, but I didn't think it would be suitable for the graphic design site.

I have three websites for which I need to make a spreadsheet of all the images and their dimensions - which there are a **lot** of. Is there any software/generator etc that can do this in bulk and automatically? If not, it is going to be a long and painful day!

Comment: Since this is a site for *programmers*, a question about *how to write a program that does this* would be more appropriate. It's not even very difficult in almost all mainstream languages.

Comment: Sorry, yep, very true. Should I rewrite my question and title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get all images from the website(s) in question. Using wget:

   `wget -r -A .gif,.jpeg,.jpg,.png http://www.example.com/`
2. Get the dimentions using [`identify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php)

   `find . -type f -name "\(*.gif|*.jp?g|*.png\)" -exec identify -format '%b,%w %h\n' {} \; > sizes.csv`
3. Open `sizes.csv`